# ES 6 Class : Access "this" in another scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a ES6 Class in NodeJS 4.
In the constructor, I want to modify the prototype of an object, so that it now use this class instance to perform an operation.

But, of course, in the prototype scope, `this` doesn't refer to the instance of the class i'm creating.

```
class Generic {
  constructor() {
    this.myClass = util._extend({}, aClass); //shallow copy
    this.myClass.prototype.run = function(fn) {
      var str = this.toString;
      //in the next line, _this_ should refer to the Generic instance.
      this.run(str, fn);
    };
  }

  do() {
    return this.myClass;
  }

  run(str, fn) {
    ...
  }
```

How can I refer the Generic class instance being created on the myClass prototype scope ?

Comment: So to get this straight, you want `this.toString` to refer to the new instance, but `this.run()` to refer to the Generic instance. It's worth mentioning you really should look at the `extends` keyword and how it works with classes.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Exactly.

Comment: In which case, the `var that = this` solution provided by Oriol is what you're looking for. Please note that it smells to me that your approach is wrong and that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/166899).

Comment: Please please please do not create *classes* as parts of instances. As Madara said, we have no idea what you want to do here, but you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

- `bind`:

  ```
  this.myClass.prototype.run = (function(fn) {
    // `this` is the Generic instance.
  }).bind(this);
  ```
- `that`:

  ```
  var that = this;
  this.myClass.prototype.run = function(fn) {
    // `that` is the Generic instance.
  };
  ```
- Arrow functions:

  ```
  this.myClass.prototype.run = fn => {
    // `this` is the Generic instance.
  };
  ```

Comment: Only the `that = this` solution is viable here. I believe he wants both `this`s on the same function.